# Image recognition neural network

Tags: image-recognition

Sorry for this, probably, very naive question, but: 
1) Are there any "pre-made" neural networks for image recognition exists? ("Pre-made" means they require minimum coding so you could just train them on your picture database)
2) If they are, is there something which would work on Windows?